# Tem como configura uma imagem na ImageView para que ela pegue a tela inteira do celular

Tags: android, xml, imagem

O seguinte declaro normal a `ImageView` :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/imagem"/>
```

porém a imagem não ocupa toda tela.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Experimente incluir a seguinte propriedade:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Porém, dependendo da sua imagem, pode não manter a mesma qualidade e proporção, então você tem que usar uma boa imagem para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, utilize `MATCH_PARENT` quando você quer que sua `View` ocupe todo o espaço de tela. A propriedade `FILL_PARENT` foi descontinuada a partir da API 8.

Dê uma olhada no parâmetro `android:adjustViewBounds` para fazer com que sua `ImageView` se redimensione sozinha para se adaptar a sua imagem rescalada.

Depois, você pode mudar a maneira com que sua imagem é redimensionada usando o parâmetro `android:scaleType`, [aqui você pode ver as propriedades](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) que melhor lhe atendem.